# RxJava Add new objects into stream

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to inject new object into a potentially existing stream.

Let's say I have this : 
ItemUtils.java

```
public static void processItems(List<Item> items) {
    Observable.from(items)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(ItemUtils::doSomeHeavyProcessing)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe();
}
```

And in another class :

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

public void onClick() {
    processItems(list);
}
```

---

Is it possible to inject the items into one unique stream of Items every time an impatient user presses the button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If List itmes is kind of queue where user can add more Items while processItems is already started, you should use [Subjects](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

```
Queue<Item> items = new LinkedList<>();
PublishSubject<Item> subject = PublishSubject.create(); 

...
//subscribe once and supply new items in onClick
subject.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(ItemUtils::doSomeHeavyProcessing)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();

...
public void onClick() {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        subject.onNext(queue.remove());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, the question lacks precision though so this answer is pretty generic.

The basic idea would be to use [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concat(rx.Observable, rx.Observable)) or variations of this operator.

So for example depending on what the code really need to do it could be :

```
public static void processItems(List<Item> items) {
    Observable<ProcessdItem> processedItems = Observable.from(items)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(ItemUtils::doSomeHeavyProcessing)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    Observable.concat(
        Observable.just(ProcessedItems.preProcessed()),
        processedItems
    ).subscribe();
}
```

Or in the nested observable.

```
public static void processItems(List<Item> items) {
    Observable.from(items)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(i ->
            Observable.just(ProcessedItems.preProcessed())
                .concatWith(ItemUtils::doSomeHeavyProcessing))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe();
}
```